# Connecting an infected HDD externally to another PC

Tags: hard-drive, virus, malware

I have a laptop HDD that contains one or more viruses. I want to remove it and connect it via a SATA-to-USB connector to my desktop computer, right-click the drive, then click "scan for viruses". Is this safe?

Comment: Since we don't know which operating system you use, you have to got with this general advice `Disable autostart before connecting` (Thats not needed on Win7)

Comment: The desktop uses Win7, the laptop WinXp, so it looks like im good

Comment: Wait a minute. I thought there was a windows patch for Win7 some time ago which disabled autostart in general. But I can't find a proper source in the short time to prove this.

Comment: Got it: I don't know if your system is up to date so please check this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715/en-us). In doubt you can use "the Microsoft Fix it 50471" which is linked there.

Comment: thanks. even without the fix, however, the system would always prompt me for an action when connecting an external hdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the safest way to solve your problem is just to boot up from usb flash that is designed to cure viruses and actually cure them all. look at [Dr.Web® LiveUSB](http://www.freedrweb.com/liveusb/?lng=en), [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/8092) and any other antivirus that has free live usb image disk for download. using this approach you don't even have to get your hdd out of notebook.

Comment: thanks. whats the best free program of this kind that i can burn onto a cd?

Comment: nevermind i just found it http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-antivir-rescue-system avira one of the highest (if not the highest) detection rates in the industry (but unfortunatley also quite a high rate of false positives)

Comment: every antivirus nowadays cures almost all the same viruses as any other one. the reasons to choose one instead of another are relativity of developer to your geographical area (they will find new viruses that you could get infected with supposedly a bit faster than others), speed, compatibility.